# What properties does $R$ have to satisfy for $R=\operatorname{graph}(f)$ for some function $f:A\to B$?

Tags: relations

Given a relation $R$ between $A$ and $B$, what properties does $R$ have to satisfy for $R=\operatorname{graph}(f)$ for some function $f:A\to B$?

Comment: To every elements in $a \in A$, there is a unique element in $b \in B$ such that $aRb$?

Comment: What does "graph(f)" mean?

Comment: @Acccumulation The graph of a function $f:A \to B$ is the set $\{(x, f(x)) : x \in A \}$.

Answer (score 0):

You need two properties.

1) For each $x\in A$ there is a $y\in B$ such that $(x,y)\in R$

2) If $(x_1,y_1)\in R$  and $(x_2,y_2)\in R$, then  $$x_1 = x_2 \implies y_1=y_2$$

Comment: I think the second point is a bit unclear. Perhaps rewrite it as "If $(x,y_1), (x,y_2) \isin R$ then $y_1=y_2$"?

Comment: Thanks, I have edited my answer.